# ng serve | Will not cast to ther devices

Tags: node.js, angular, express, https, server

I run my app to my local machine via ssl like this:

```
ng serve --ssl --host: 0.0.0.0
```

so it is up at: https://localhost:4200

I also using my ipv4 adress which is: XXX.XXX.XX.XXX to make my requests to the server via my services, so i make my api calls like this: https://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:80/api...

In my back end, I have created an https server so my API calls are been made via  https

Everything works great to my desktop

> **Problem is:** The app wont cast to ther devices.. it wont even load and
>   after some time i get the msg this site cannot be reached

Answer (score 0):

The built in webpack server that is used for `ng serve` is not meant for production or sharing to other computers, it is only supposed to work on local for development because of security reasons. You should consider hosting a compiled version with a separate web server such as nginx. If you absolutely NEED the built in webpack one to work, you can force it to bind to all of your IP addresses with this:

`ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`

You may need to disable the host check as well:

`ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check`

Comment: dont agree with you.. it is meant for sharing to other devices for testing purposes in developement mode.. In my question I am also mentioning that i use --host 0.0.0.0 but still wont work

Answer (score 0):

You can access this, but you might need to turn off your Firewall, this mostly happens in windows machines.

Try [turning it off](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-disable-the-windows-firewall-2624505) and accessing the IP from other machine.